# Missing Email and Password Authentication in Android Studio's Firebase tool

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

[image]

As you can see from the photo above, I don't see the email and password authentication option. It is missing in my Firebase tool. I am trying to create a login and log out activity sample app and I wanted to use the email and password authentication option, but it is not here at all. Anyone knows where can I find it/ enable it?

Comment: you can enable from console.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily choose authenticate using a custom authentification system (the third option)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These are only shortcuts and not showing all authentication options
Just connect your project with firebase and add dependencies from this toolbar and enable Email authentication from the firebase console in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your Firebase console and follow this steps i have marked on the next screenshots

Click on Authentication, then on Sign-in method
[image]

Then on the email/password line you have to click on the icon with a pencil and activate the switch i marked on next photo

[image]